# ASP.NET 3.5.1 GridView in Update Panel requerying on row select?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, select, refresh

I have a GridView that is bound to an ObjectDataSource, and I am handling the full row select using the standard solution provdided all over of putting this line in the OnRowDataBound():

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

All of this is working swimmingly, except that I am noticing my ObjectDataSource is being hit each time the row selection changes.  I am not doing a BindData() anywhere in the row selection code behind, and since the data isn't changing as a result of the select I really don't see why the grid needs to rebind.  I am letting the gridview handle paging and sorting, but again, selection doesn't change the contents so I don't think that should effect it.

I have tried turning the view state on for the grid (very small amount of data) and it had no effect.  I set the UpdatePanel to conditional updates and children as triggers=false, but that caused the data to still be queried but no update to occur to the screen (LOL!).

Any GridView gurus out there want to take a stab at this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the following in your Page_Load():

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{

}
```

This is something developers miss a lot!  Follow your events and you'll likely see that somewhere an event is fired OnPostBack and you're calling your DB code.

Comment: As it turns out no... but it would not have surpised me! LOL.  I think I've decided that the page is way to complicated to boil down to a simple example, and it's working as is, and I'm not passing the data in view state this way, so I've decided to be happy.  Thanks though! :-)